# Hyphonopoly error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Tags: javascript, hyphenator

I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
at Hyphenopoly.js:153:11
at Hyphenopoly.js:209:7
at Hyphenopoly.js:933:3
```

I checked my links, errors in files (didn't find anything). I want Hophenopoly to control text wrapping in a specific block (messages_container), but instead I have this error.The error has nothing to do with the code. I deleted it, but the error remained